# Can't calculate % of row in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Product types A, B, C, D
Each type has numerous products, say type A has 100 products, type B 50 etc..

```
product#    product type
01          A
02          A
...
101         B
102         B
...
```

I want to calculate % of products sold per product type. My pivot table looks like:

```
          total    sold     %sold
A         100      50       50%
B         50       20       40%
```

I can get pivot table to show "total" and "sold" columns, but how do I calculate "%sold" column?

Comment: I've tried to add a calculated field but in the calculation I can't specify "total" or "sold" columns...

Answer (score 0):

For each item, use a 0 to represent 'Not Sold' and 1 to represent 'Sold'. Then use an average of that column in the pivot table.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be

```
=caculate(sold,product type ="A")/caculate(total, product type ="A")
```